# Character turning solid black instead of reverting to original

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, transparent

Character turns transparent until the timer ends, then instead of flicking back to the original colour it turns flat black.

```
    private Color c;

    void Start(){
    c = thePlayer.rend.color;
    }

public void HurtPlayer(int damageToTake)
    {
        healthCount -= damageToTake;
        UpdateHeartMeter ();
        StartCoroutine ("iFrames");
    }

    IEnumerator iFrames(){
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (10, 11, true);
            c.a = 0.5f;
            thePlayer.rend.color = c;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
            c.a = 1f;
            thePlayer.rend.color = c;
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (10, 11, false);
    }
```

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hiAI.jpg

Comment: Can you try holding the original color in another variable and assign that to your object when timer ends instead of manipulating `a` it probably modifies original color

Comment: Also what is `rend` here in this line `c = thePlayer.rend.color;`

Comment: @AliKanat that refers to the players sprite renderer

Comment: Might sound silly also but how would I go about storing the original

Comment: The problem is not about that i think. I tested your code it works for me. I think the problem is how to access the `SpriteRenderer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works for me i am not sure how you access the `SpriteRenderer` problem might be there. I only started the coroutine with click of a button since i do not know when you apply this. This code is attached to a Sprite.

```
private Color c;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    c = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        StartCoroutine("ChangeColor");
    }
}
IEnumerator ChangeColor()
{
    c.a = 0.5f;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = c;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    c.a = 1f;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = c;
}
```

Comment: I apply this with OnTriggerEnter2D, and the rend is accessed through the PlayerController script from the LevelManager(which handles hp etc) script

Comment: So you are sure you successfully access rend? What does it log when you do `Debug.Log(rend)` Can you share your `PlayerController` script as well.

Comment: Okay it looks like I just fixed it using `c = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;` where gameobject was referring to my player thanks for the help!!

Comment: I believe it was looking at the alpha of the sprite and not the alpha of the color aspect of the renderer

Comment: Cool i understand. If it helped please click green arrow so that others can see it is solved. Thanks